# Possible to control the JIT-Compiler

Tags: c#, .net, jit

I have written a small application for showing time series graphically, and on the click of a button, filter them by multiplying a complex transfer function in the frequency domain and show the filtered time series.

The needed Fourier-transform is a well-known unmanaged native implementation ([FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)) used with interop. There is also some copying around, zero-padding to the spectrum, computing the samples of the complex transfer function and of course displaying the series (with GDI+ inside a form), all in managed c#.

For longer time series (>100k samples) it does not surprise me that there are short delays (fraction of a second to a few seconds). What did surprise me was that upon the first button click (and the corresponding computations described above) the delay is much longer than upon the subsequent clicks (no I am not caching results). Say 2 seconds instead of 0.2 second for example.

**Is it likely that this must be the effect of the JIT-Compiler?** If yes, is it that during the first call the code is interpreted and during the following calls it is run natively? Or must it rather be the compile time itself that causes the additional delay?

**Is there any way to monitor the action of the JIT-compiler (e.g. to find out if it causes said delay).**

Finally, since the phenomenon is a little irritating for the user, **is there any way to instruct the JIT-compiler to compile some selected methods in advance instead of just-in-time?**

Comment: @pstrjds: thank you, looks very similar to my problem domain. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Follow-up: It was not JIT-related. I tried NGEN and it first seemed that this solved the problem. But then I noticed that the problem just did not occur when I started the app outside the development environment (I use SharpDevelop for that). Somehow the devenv slows down the first call (or the JIT compilation) extremely. Anyways if it's running okay when standalone I consider my problem solved.

Comment: JIT overhead is not what you'd suspect first when you pinvoke native code.  More likely is disk overhead, digging up the DLL and its dependencies, maybe non-trivial initialization.  In which case you'd try to hide it by running the function early with fake data, at the same time something else is taking time.  Splash-screen style.